# RestController @requestbody always recibe empty pojo in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a problem i want to recibe a POJO in post but i always recibe a empty POJO

Here is my interface:

```
package com.test.api;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import com.test.beans.LoginResponse;
import com.test.core.statistics.FGService;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
//
@RequestMapping({"/key", "/key/"})
public interface KeyLoginAPI {


    @PostMapping(path = "newkey",consumes = "application/json",produces = "application/json")

    public LoginResponse generateKey( @RequestBody(required = true) LoginResponse login) throws ResponseStatusException;
}
```

Here is my controller how should return the pojo:

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import com.test.api.KeyLoginAPI;
import com.test.beans.LoginResponse;
//import com.test.model.DlsLlaves;

@RestController
public class KeyLoginApiController implements KeyLoginAPI{

    @Override
    public LoginResponse generateKey(LoginResponse login) throws ResponseStatusException {

        return login;
    }

    private void authenticate(Integer providerid, String key) {


    }


}
```

And here is my POJO im using lombok for getters and setters:

```
package com.test.beans;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoginResponse extends DefaultResponse{
    private String token;


}
```

and my request is:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/key/newkey HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 81
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

{
    "code": 1,
    "message": "message example",
    "token": "token example"
}
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 15:02:20 GMT

{"code":null,"message":null,"token":null}
```

also i try to use a pojo without lombok and also dont work, and i dont know how to do, i hope some can help me

Comment: Why do you have two same mappings `{"/key", "/key/"}`. In addition, can you try `@PostMapping(value = "newkey"...` instead? Note `value` instead of `path`

Comment: Hi @FedericoPiazza  , I change    `@RequestMapping("key") and @PostMapping(value = "newkey")` and neither work

Comment: Beware of the slashes. Check and use this `@RequestMapping("/key")` and `@PostMapping("/newkey")`

Comment: Btw, in your question you say your request is not working, but your request it is... it seems your response is not. Are you sure your response object is well populated?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza 
also try that and it doesn't work

Comment: Don't use an interface. Just put this in your controller, I don't trust your annotations

Comment: @FedericoPiazza
maybe I asked the wrong question, in my endpoint I want to receive a pojo and return that same pojo but it always arrives empty and for so it returns `{"code":null,"message":null,"token":null}`

Comment: It is not "correct" to receive a "response" object and return it as response. You should receive a "request" object and then populate your response. Check then answer I posted

Comment: I delete my interface and modify my controler    `@RestController
@RequestMapping("/key")
public class KeyLoginApiController {
 @PostMapping(value = "/newkey",consumes = "application/json",produces = "application/json")
 public LoginResponse generateKey(LoginResponse login) throws ResponseStatusException {
  return login;
 }`

Comment: @FedericoPiazza yes i going to change this, 
I have it that way just to do tests

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this more as a comment than an answer since I need better formatting.

Your code is a bit awkward to me, don't use the interface and use a regular class with the annotations. In addition, create a brand new object for the response.

Use this code instead:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/key")
public class KeyLoginApiController {

    @PostMapping("/newkey")
    public LoginResponse generateKey(@RequestBody LoginResponse login)
        LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
        response.setMessage("something");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Once you confirm your request body works, then continue with your test by returning the `login`